# React not receive message signalr .net

Tags: reactjs, .net, signalr, client, receiver

im trying to implement alerts from backed to my React front with signalr, but actually the client connect successful but not receive alerts(messages) when I send from the backend:

**Backend .net 6:**

Interface:

```
namespace BucciaratiMessenger.Hubs
{
  public interface IAlertClient
  {
    Task ReceiveAlert(Alert alert);
  }
}
```

Hub:

```
namespace BucciaratiMessenger.Hubs
{
   public class AlertHub : Hub<IAlertClient>
   {}
}
```

Program:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("ClientPermission", policy =>
  {
    policy.AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowCredentials();
  });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapHub<AlertHub>("hubs/alert");
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AlertController :Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<AlertHub, IAlertClient> _alertHub;

    public AlertController(IHubContext<AlertHub, IAlertClient> alertHub)
    {
        this._alertHub = alertHub;
    }

    [Route(nameof(AlertController.RegisterAlert)), HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterAlert(Alert entity)
    {
        try
        {
            await _alertHub.Clients.All.ReceiveAlert(entity);
            ...
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**React Client:**

```
const HeaderComp = (props) => {
  const[connection, setConnection] = useState(null)
  const [ alert, setAlert ] = useState([]);
  const latestAlert = useRef(null)
  const[countAlert, setCountAlert] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('http://localhost:5146/hubs/alert')
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (connection) {
        connection.start()
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Connected!')

                connection.on('ReceiveAlert', message => {
                    const updatedChat = [...latestAlert.current]
                    updatedChat.push(message)                    
                    setAlert(updatedChat)
                    setCountAlert(countAlert+1)
                });
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
    }
  }, [connection]);

  return (
    <Layout>
      ...
    </Layout>  
  )
}

export default HeaderComp
```

In the Console.log I get success connection to http://localhost:5146/hubs/alert.
When I send to the method controller any message, not occur any exception, but the client not receive the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem were the two useEffect, only need one:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:5146/hubs/alert')
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

    connection.start()
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Connected!');

        connection.on('ReceiveAlert', message => {
           setCountAlert(countAlert+1)
          
        });
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Connection failed: ', e));
}, []);
```